# RStudio Code Snippets: How to change order of snippets in auto-complete

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I'm using customized code snippets in RStudio (version 1.1.383) to quickly insert frequently used lines of code. I use shortcuts for the snippets that start with the same letter for different areas, e.g. every code snippet related to ggplot2 starts with gg_ . This works really great, but there is one more thing that would but very helpful, and that is to be able to define the order of snippets, so that the most important ones are presented first.

How can I **change** the **order** in which the **snippets** are suggested in **auto-complete**? The order now isn't alphabetic, and also not the same as the order in the edit snippets dialog.

Thanks

Comment: Is the order related to most recently used, or frequency of use?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and with some experimentation discovered that snippets are presented in the REVERSE order of their entry in the snipper editor. Checked on RStudio v1.2.5033
It's not exactly an intuitive solution, but at least it allows for customisation to personal requirements.

Issue submitted: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6891